# Ошибка маршрутизации Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, маршрутизация, symfony3

Создал новый бандл, прописал `routing`, при загрузке страницы выскакивает ошибка `No route found for "GET /"`.

Контроллер:

```
namespace Trainer\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

/**
 * Class PageController
 * @package Trainer\UserBundle\Controller
 */
class PageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function indexAction() {
        return $this->render('@TrainerUser/Page/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

routing.yml:

```
trainer_homepage:
path:     /
defaults: { _controller: TrainerUserBundle:Page:index }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в файле `/app/config/routing.yml`. Генератор бандла сгенерировал этот файл так:

```
trainer_class:
    resource: "@TrainerClassBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

trainer_user:
    resource: "@TrainerUserBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Поэтому `routing.yml` из `TrainerUserBundle` был не виден и следовательно выскакивала ошибка. Немного изменил файл и всё заработало:

```
trainer_class:
    resource: "@TrainerClassBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

trainer_user:
    resource: "@TrainerUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```